# CatalystX::SimpleLogin have multiple realms

Tags: perl, authentication, catalyst

I need to create an authentication system for two types of users, clients and staff. I would like to use two separate realms to authenticate them (via [Catalyst::Plugin::Authentication](https://metacpan.org/module/Catalyst::Plugin::Authentication)), however I would then like to limit that the clients can only see the client controller, whereas staff are free to see both the client controller and the staff controller. In the past whenever I've needed to only authenticate one type of user, I've used [CatalystX::SimpleLogin](https://metacpan.org/module/CatalystX::SimpleLogin) because this makes authenticating users very simple, as well as things like remembering which URL to redirect the user to if they had to login to access a page, etc. However, I cannot figure out a way to do this using `CatalystX::SimpleLogin`. Has anyone done this before or can anyone think of a way to do it? Or am I better off just straight using `Catalyst::Plugin::Authentication` to accomplish what I want? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want are roles via the `Catalyst::Plugin::Authorization::Roles`. This allows you to easily separate your different user types. Here is an example from the `Catalyst::Plugin::Authentication` documentation:

```
use Catalyst qw/
    ...
    Authorization::Roles
/;

sub edit : Local {
    my ( $self, $c ) = @_;

    $c->detach("unauthorized") unless $c->check_user_roles("edit");

    # do something restricted here
}
```

Comment: This is a good suggestion. But do you know how I could redirect users to different pages once they login based upon their roles?